# How to get the text from local textfile in xcode project

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2

I kept a file in supporting files. now i want to retrive the text from that file to my textfield in xcode. please help me regarding this. also please post any code if possible.
i have used the below codes., but i cant access.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iPhone.txt" ofType:@"txt"];    
NSString *textData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSLog(@"Some text from a file of %@", textData);
NSLog(@"The length of the string is %u",[textData length]);
```

Error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "FirstInMacViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
>   *** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 1):

That error has nothing to do with the code you posted.  It looks like you've mistakenly disconnected the `view` outlet for your nib.  Open up your nib and drag with the right mouse button from the file's owner to the top level view and connect the `view` outlet.